# How can I create two segues for a single button in a view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a root view controller - which is a simple page presented to the user. In this page, there is a UIBarButton that goes to the user profile page.

When the user is in its profile, he/she'll have a back button that will allow him/her to go back to the root view controller.

However, the root view controller is different for admins and clients (there is one standard view controller for admins and one standard view controller for clients).

How can I create two segues that are triggered by the 'Back' profile button? I mean, depending on who is currently logged in (an admin or a client), I would like to go back to their respective pages.

The client cannot go back to the admin's page and neither vice versa.

Is there any way to create these two segues? Or even another/better way? I have tried to do that using storyboard, but when I create the second segue, it deletes the first one linked to the button.

Comment: You simply need to use `if ... else`. Store the user type somewhere and create the segues depending on the stored user type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off of Nirav D's answer, use an `if...else` with the condition that they are an admin or client.  But don't `control+drag` from the button itself, `control+drag` from the ViewController as seen in the images below.
[image: Click and drag to admin VC]
[image: Click and drag to client VC]

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do that but there is other way for that, create two segue bwtween `SenderViewController` and `DestinatrionViewController`. After that set action for your button and perform the segue according to your requirements.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if condition {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier1", sender: nil)
    }
    else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier2", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: and I think this is the way you should do it even for a single segue - it keeps all of your implementation visible in the code, and makes debugging a lot simpler

Comment: @Russell I will also do this way.

Answer (score 0):

you should handle it in your code.

```
@IBAction func backClick() {
    if isAdmin /* check condition here  */ {
      // admin work
    } else {
      // normal user work here
    }
}
```

Then let create segue from storyboard and give it an identifier.

If you want perform segue, let use

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: nil)
```

if you want go back.

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Hope it help.